# What is the difference between request.POST.get and request.POST

Tags: django, forms

usually I use POST or GET requests except for GET.get paginations, but I don't understand the concept there are only two possibilities POST or GET .

example even if there is the same effect I do not understand the difference between
`request.GET.get('page') and request.GET["page"] request.POST['rate'] and request.POST.get('rate')`

Answer (score 1):

`request.POST` is a `dict`-like object.

For `dict`s and their derivatives, `d[x]` equates to indexing into the `dict` by key `x`, and `d.get(x, default)` is a method that is equivalent to indexing, except it returns a default value instead of throwing a `KeyError`. If the default value is not set, `d.get()` will return None.

Answer (score 0):

`request.POST['sth']` will raise a KeyError exception if 'sth' is not in request.POST.

`request.POST.get('sth')` will return None if 'sth' is not in request.POST